# React native crop image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, crop

I have a little problem with cropping images in react native.
As you can see the example below

[image]

I want to crop the image inside the white rectangle, I don't know if I'm using the wrong formula or not

```
  takePicture = async() => {
    console.log("pic")
    if (this.camera != null) {
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();

      /**
       * Calcul
       */
      const x_axis_scale = data.width / width
      const y_axis_scale = data.height / height
      var x_coord_int = 70 * x_axis_scale;
      var y_coord_int = 120 * y_axis_scale;
      var rect_width_int = 200 * x_axis_scale;
      var rect_height_int = 70 * y_axis_scale
      const res = await ImageEditor.cropImage(data.uri, {
        offset: {x: x_coord_int, y: y_coord_int},
        size: {
          width:rect_width_int,
          height: rect_height_int
        }
      })
      this.setState({
        imageCrop: res
      })
    }
  };
```

It doesn'tt crop correcty.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry , i can't help about this issue . But there is a library [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) which can help with cropping issue . Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but i want to crop it without crop UI interface.. can you get it?

Comment: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-image-editor This library can help you out.