# React-Native-Crop-Image doesn't work on android , How to crop images on android and it should be same for ios also

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I have tried this library [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker/v/0.4.2) as suggested on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978620/react-native-crop-image)

I have followed each and every step mentioned [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker/v/0.4.2)

1. Run `npm i react-native-image-crop-picker@0.4.2`
2. `import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';`
   then

> ImagePicker.openPicker({
> width: 300,
> height: 400,
> cropping: true
> }).then(image => {
> console.log(image);
> });

Also in `// file: android/settings.gradle` have added the below code

> include ':react-native-image-crop-picker'
> project(':react-native-image-crop-picker').projectDir = new
> File(settingsDir,
> '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/android')

Also as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker/v/0.4.2) have added required code in `build.gradle` & `MainActivity.java` file

But this is not working for me on `Android` but working perfectly on `iOS` . On `Android` I have given to crop images by scale type only not as flexible crop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have faced the problem for version issue. You should try [react-native-amazing-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-amazing-cropper) . It works same for both the `Android` and `iOS`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found out that we need the following line in our AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ... >

  ...

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace" />
```

Enjoy.